# How can I change the values of ndarray on condition?

Tags: numpy

I have an array=[5,7,8,1,2] and I want to return 1 if Element >4,and else 0. So the desired result is [1,1,1,0,0]. I tried to by array.apply(lambda x: 1 if x>4 else 0). But it doesn’t work

Comment: `array2 = (array>4)*1` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic numpy operation.

```
check = array>4
```

That will give you a boolean array of the same shape, with the associated truth values. You can then multiply by 1 to get 1's and 0's, since true and false have integer values.

You can also use numpy.where to be explicit.

```
out = numpy.zeros(array.shape)
out[numpy.where(check)] = 1
```